# How to insert an RTMP url from an adobe streaming server (rtmp://example.com/myvideo.flv) in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, files, media

I need to create a video gallery and would like some advice on how to view flash videos on drupal 7.

The url I have to insert are rtmp (rtmp://example.com/myvideo.flv).

Any ideas on what modules to install and the steps to follow?

I read on the previous questions about flowplayer but it's only supported on Drupal 6.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22drupal+7%22+embed+flv I'd also advise looking at http://drupal.org/project/media and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065400/what-is-the-best-drupal-module-that-allows-me-to-embedd-videos-from-youtube-or-u may be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You can use JWPLAYER , and here is an example for how you setup the streaming

1- in the page header you include the jwplayer js library
2- follow the embedding guide "http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player"
3- use the RTMP changes as it's documented here http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming/

So your simple code will look like this;

```
 
 jwplayer("myVideo").setup({
     file: "rtmp://example.com/application/mp4:myVideo.mp4",
     image: "/assets/myVideo.jpg",
     height: 360,
     width: 640
    });
```